# javascript xmlhttprequest always gets status 0

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, runtime-error

I want to query my server triggered by a button click. The function gets called  and the aync request is started. Most of the time it readyState reaches 4, sometimes only 2 - but the status always remains 0.
The onerror function always triggers, but (as many other have experienced) gives not much info about the problem.

```
function getServiceVal() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/myservice?param=1"));

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        console.log("-->" + xmlhttp.readyState + ", " + xmlhttp.status)
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            console.log(xmlhttp.responseText.length)
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.onerror  = function(e) {
      console.log('There was an error! - ' + xmlhttp + ", " + e + ", ");
    };

    xmlhttp.send(null);
};
```

I also tried the onload function - without further success. Has anybody a idea where the problem could be? CORS shouldn't be it since i use a relative path.
I am testing on localhost, URL is "http://localhost:8042/servicetest.html"

Output of the snippet always looks like this:

```
-->2, 0
-->4, 0
There was an error! - [object XMLHttpRequest], [object ProgressEvent], 
-->2, 0
-->2, 0
-->4, 0
There was an error! - [object XMLHttpRequest], [object ProgressEvent],
```

Thanks a lot for any help & hints!

*****BREAKING NEWS*****

After concentrating on many hours on the javascript code I took a look at the html code invoking it. And really that made the difference. Initially I used a form (because I want to hand over parameters) and invoke the javascript at the submit event.
Now I changed to a simple button and - tadaa - it works. I don't know why, though:

```
    <!--form onsubmit="getServiceVal()">
        <input ref="input"/>
        <button>Get Value</button>
    </form-->
    <input type="button" value="This Button!" onclick="getServiceVal();">
```

This now works, the former in the comment does not. I was not aware that the kind of call can have such an impact.

Comment: `The onerror function is always triggers` What exactly is the ProgressEvent error? Sounds like the request isn't completing

Comment: Indeed, that's what I think as well, but don't know the reason. The ProgressEvent is what the javascript runtime hands over to the onerror method. Same in chromium and firefox.

Comment: Do check `xmlhttp.statusText` as well or better inspect browser's network tab and monitor XHR

Comment: Did you actually check what the ProgressEvent is, though?

Comment: The statusText is empty on both functions. In the browser's network tab I see the XHR, with the status field empty, all other parameters at 0.

Comment: Regarding ProgressEvent, it should be an object that tracks the download progress of larger content, I guess. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ProgressEvent

Comment: Yes, so log it and see what the object contains - see if there's an error message in it. (To ping other users when you reply to them, put @username in your replies)

Comment: @CertainPerformance - thanks for the tip! Regarding the ProgressEvent, its properties are 'undefined'. Yet I made some progress, the behaviour might be rooted in a wrong call in the html code that I did (see last paragraph on my question). Thanks again for caring.

Comment: That doesn't make sense - if it's an object it *will* have properties (unless it was created via `Object.create(null)` or something like that). Eg you can just `console.log(e)` in a modern browser and explore the event

Comment: I did:
`       console.log('There was an error! - ' + xmlhttp + ", " + e + ", " + e.statusText + ", " + e.status);`
gives
    `There was an error! - [object XMLHttpRequest], [object ProgressEvent], undefined, undefined`

Comment: use `e.target.statusText` and `e.target.status` instead, because progressEvent does not have the XHR fields, e.target does - oh, and if you coerce the objects to strings, then the console output is useless anyway

Comment: having said that, status of 0 usually means either a) you're using `file:///` protocol or b) you have a CORS error - but that can't be the case as your request is same origin

Comment: `I did` No, log the event *alone* so you can look at the object itself, rather than a useless `[object ProgressEvent]` string (remember to `@` if you want people to see that you've replied to them)

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for the logging tip, i'm somewhat spoiled by Java
But not much more insight, I knew the content of the object from VS Code debugger already. The objects look pretty much the same, regardless if created via the button inside the form, or 'standalone'.

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for the hin again, I found nothing in the event object that told me what the problem is. I will continue (as stated in the Q update) without the form. Hope this is according to standard and best practice.